# Apache under windows %100 cpu usage

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, apache-2.2

Hi since monday morning my apache server started using %100 of cpu and all the sites are responding so slow. I know it's not a good idea to use windows server 2003 and apache server together but I had to use windows. I tryed to check the status with apache status, but it does'nt show which proccess uses how much cpu (there is no cpu usage column in my apache status report). According to apache status I get mostly 2-3 requests/second. My server is VDS(IBM blade server) with 1 gb memory and 40 gb hdd. I had no problems last saturday everyting started modnay morning, Please help me to identify the problem. What tools can I use to find out what's the problem.

Comment: You can start with [Prio](http://www.prnwatch.com/prio.html) to identify address that generates most of traffic, and probably, load on your Apache server. After that try to filter those IPs to reduce load.

Comment: What is involved in your web pages?  (PHP, MySQL, Java, etc,)

Answer (score 0):

You're right that this isn't normal. For diagnosing problems like this, my first line of diagnosis under Windows is a combination of Procmon and Process Explorer, both free tools from the Sysinternals suite.

Do a Google for Sysinternals and download the suite from Microsoft. Procmon will tell you what processes are accessing what items in the filesystem and keys in the registry, while Process Explorer is like Task Managers on super-steroids. Plus the Sysinternals suite includes a lot of other handy extras.

These tools don't always point out what the problem is, but they might help you narrow down what is causing the issue.